std::bad_alloc Error When Passing cv::Mat from C++ to Python via Pybind11 for YOLO Inference
I'm working on a C++ interface to a Python model using Pybind11 and OpenCV. My goal is to read an image using OpenCV in C++ (cv::Mat), pass it to a Python YOLO model (Ultralytics), and retrieve the inference results. The Python model is loaded via Pybind11.
Initially, this setup works, but when I change my C++ interface to accept cv::Mat instead of py::object for the image input, I encounter a std::bad_alloc error during YOLO's inference in Python.
Key Code:
C++ Main Code:

py::module cv2 = py::module::import("cv2");
py::object img = cv2.attr("imread")(image_path);  // Works fine initially

cv::Mat cv_img = cv::imread(image_path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);  // Causes `std::bad_alloc`

ModelWrapper model(model_path);
while (count < 1) {
    count++;
    std::vector<std::string> results = model.predict(img);  // pass `img` to model
}

C++ Model Wrapper:
cpp

std::vector<std::string> ModelWrapper::predict(const py::object& img) {
    py::object py_result = pInstance.attr("predict")(img);
    // handle results
}

Python Model Code:
python

from ultralytics import YOLO

class MODEL:
    def __init__(self, model_path: str = "./best.pt"):
        self.model = YOLO(model_path)

    def predict(self, image: np.ndarray) -> list:
        results = self.model.predict(image)
        # process results
        return sorted_result

Problem:
When I read the image with cv::imread in C++, the program crashes with a std::bad_alloc error during the YOLO inference in Python. The error does not occur if I use Python's cv2.imread to load the image.
I’ve also verified that the image is read correctly by writing it to a file (cv::imwrite), but the error still occurs when passed to the Python model.
What I’ve Tried:

Verified the OpenCV versions in both C++ and Python are the same.
Attempted to clone the cv::Mat before passing it to Python, which did not resolve the issue.
Simplified the code to check if the issue is specific to Pybind11 or OpenCV.

Question:
Why does the std::bad_alloc error occur when using cv::imread in C++ and passing the image to Python via Pybind11, while it works when using Python's cv2.imread? How can I resolve this memory allocation issue when passing cv::Mat between C++ and Python?

so... you want a C++ interface to some python code... do you realize that OpenCV has a C++ API? there is no reason for you to need to involve Python, as far as I can see. OpenCV will load that model just fine, regardless of the language.

Maybe my description is too long and unclear. I do known  OpenCV has a C++ API, and I involve python not just for this demo python script - an 2d infer , but a 3d point cloud reconstruction task ,  it's difficult for me to rewrite it into c++ .
And at first I involve python's cv2 to imread just because when I throw my need to ChatGPT it gives this code to me and it works and unfortunately only in this way it can work - after I change my silly using python's opencv by pybind , to directly use OpenCV ' C++ API ,  I met the problem .

And  the bad_alloc problem is thrown in the python part -model.predict , but appear and disappear when I add and remove that single line cv::Mat cv_img = cv::imread(image_path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR); , even though I don't use the cv_img after that.

yes, way too long. a [mre] should fit on the screen, give or take some boilerplate that's clearly just boilerplate. what you've presented here is... I'm still summing this up... 197 lines of code-styled text, with more than a handful of non-trivial paragraphs and even a few horizontal rules to separate the post.

Thanks, I restated my question in a as concise as possible way, learned a lot!

OpenCV has a C++ API.
It has cv::imread() and so on.
You should use that instead.

Sorry, I thought I pasted the model_wrapper part but I didn't. I've pinned it at the end of the question. that' is the code I really need pybind.
